# how to trigger auto upload whilst using form plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

my problem is simple: i want to start uploading a selected image or multiple selected images as soon as the open button is pressed in the filebrowser

my code

the html

```
<div class="add_photos" onClick="document.getElementById('hide_selector').click()">+</div> // the dummy and pretty file browser trigger 
<form id="add_photos_in_album">
<input type="file" id="hide_selector" style="display:none;" name="image[]" multiple> // the back end working trigger
</form>
```

---

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        url: 'my processor file',
        type: 'POST'
    };
    $('#add_photos_in_album').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Note:**im using the jquery form plugin by malsup

---

methods tried but failed

1.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        url: 'my processor file',
        type: 'POST'
    };

$('#hide_selector').change(function() //detect change
{
  $('#add_photos_in_album').submit(function() 
  {   
   $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);return false; 
  }); 
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should send the files in the `change` event of the `hide_selector` input and not when submitting the form - or just triggering the submit of the form when the value has changed

```
$("#hide_selector").change(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=""){
        $("#add_photos_in_album").submit();
    }
});
```